# Flutter - How to make a reusable button change its image and color?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a button that I can use on multiple different pages. I want to be able to change the image and fill the OutlineButton with a color when it's pressed. How can this be accomplished?

```
class BackArrowButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final GestureTapCallback onPressed;
  BackArrowButton({@required this.onPressed, this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlineButton(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: child,
      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Color(0xff1A1A1A)),
      highlightElevation: 0.0,
      highlightedBorderColor: Color(0xFF1A1A1A),
      splashColor: Color(0x1F1A1A1A),
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      onPressed: onPressed,
    );
  }
```

This is what I call on multiple pages to show the button.

```
BackArrowButton(
  child: ClipOval(
    child: Container(
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/icons/arrow_back.png',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pop(context, '/home');
  },
),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your button a statefullWidget and add setState to the onPress call.

```
class BackArrowButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final GestureTapCallback onPressed;

  BackArrowButton({@required this.onPressed, this.child});

  @override
  _BackArrowButtonState createState() => _BackArrowButtonState();
}


class _BackArrowButtonState extends State<BackArrowButton> {



  @override
  void initState() {
    _color = Colors.green;
    super.initState();
  }

  Color _color;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlineButton(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: widget.child,
      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Color(0xff1A1A1A)),
      highlightElevation: 0.0,
      highlightedBorderColor: _color,
      splashColor: Color(0x1F1A1A1A),
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      onPressed: (){
        setState((){
           _color = Colors.red;
        });
        widget.onPressed();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's saying the function 'setState' isn't used.

Comment: forgot some brackets!